# In ansible what is the best way to manage Global and groupwise vars

Tags: ansible

Currently my playbook to create user accounts and

```
- name: Create the necessary users
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    users:
      - name: user1
        ssh_keys:
          - XXXXX
      - name: user2
        ssh_keys:
          - YYYYY
    users_to_remove: [] # array of user names to remove
```

The tasks to create the user follow this and are quite basic.
Currently this setup creates the accounts on all hosts. I have ~15-20 hosts split in about 5 groups, and I am trying to come up with a clean solution which lets me create users in only a few specific groups instead of all groups. I would like to leave the vars in the playbook if at all possible.

I am hoping there is a way I can implement something like

```
- name: user2
  ssh_keys:
    - YYYYY
  group: all # or group name
```

Is it possible to do this? Or is there any more prefered way to manage this?
The only way I can think of is to create a full directory structure for group vars and add the dict there, possible split one dict for global users and one for users specific to a particular group and merge (Since ansible doesnt merge the vars right? AFAIK the group vars just overwrite the global vars)

Answer (score 1):

Would *ansible_host* variable help you?

```
- name: Set authorized key
  authorized_key:
    user: user2
    key: YYYYY
  when: ansible_host in groups.group_XY
```

Comment: Looks very promising, I can use "all" as a default value i guess, but I was wondering if there was a more "Ansible" way in defining variables.

Comment: Do you know if there was a equivalent for groups? ansible_group ? I am not able to find any such variable

Comment: There is a variable *groups*. I edited the answer.